# How to issue Git commands from a script?

Tags: python, git, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to make a commit to a file, create a new branch in a bitbucket repository in my python script, how can I do that?

Comment: No, how do i link to the bitbucket repository

Answer (score 1):

You could run the git commands as a typical shell command, but you may instead want to use a python binding for git, such as [pygit2](https://www.pygit2.org/index.html). The documentation has simple recipes for things like [committing](https://www.pygit2.org/recipes/git-commit.html).